# calculating distance for every ca atoms to each other atoms

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data like below in a text file

```
ATOM      2  CA  ALA A   2      25.587 -25.158  -9.461  1.00 59.65           C
ATOM      7  CA  LYS A   3      23.789 -25.564 -12.791  1.00 56.33           C
ATOM     16  CA  ILE A   4      23.990 -21.786 -13.168  1.00 47.06           C
ATOM     24  CA  ASP A   5      27.381 -20.176 -12.568  1.00 45.48           C
ATOM     32  CA  ASN A   6      27.343 -16.666 -11.069  1.00 38.90           C
ATOM     40  CA  ALA A   7      23.585 -16.811 -10.459  1.00 31.65           C
ATOM     45  CA  VAL A   8      22.594 -13.568  -8.716  1.00 27.49           C
ATOM     52  CA  LEU A   9      20.243 -15.584  -6.497  1.00 25.94           C
ATOM     60  CA  PRO A  10      21.933 -18.297  -4.388  1.00 26.36           C
```

I would like to calculate the distance for every  CA atom to each other atom.The column 7,8 and 9 are the coordinates of X,Y,Z respectively. To find the distance (i.e) distance=sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2+(z2-z1)**2) and finally print the values and their corresponding residue pairs.

How could I do this with python

The output like below:

```
ALA-LYS:3.66
ALA-ILE:3.33
ALA-ASP:3.42
ALA-ASN:3.54
ALA-ALA:3.32
ALA-VAL:4.32
ALA-LEU:2.65
ALA-PRO:3.22
LYS-ALA:4.35
LYS-ILE:3.33
LYS-ASP:3.67
```

And so on(The values in the output is not correct)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you load the data as nested `numpy` array (you can use a `Pandas` Dataframe too), you can make up the `distance` function to calculate the euclidean distance. The remaining things should be achievable by a nested `for` loop.

```
import numpy
def distance(x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2):
    return round(numpy.sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2+(z1-z2)**2),3)
#data is the data loaded as a nested numpy array
out = []
for i in data:
    for j in data:
        if i==j:
            continue
        d = distance(i[6],j[6],i[7],j[7],i[8],j[8])
        out.append(i[3]+'-'+j[3]+': '+str(d)+'\n')
print(out)
```